# My pages in PBI report is opening on new tab when clicked but I want to restrict this behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, powerbi

I have created my application in REACT.js and I have embeded my PBI reports into my application.

Whenever I am clicking on the button  in my PBI report, I am being redirected to new tab but I don't want to it happen.

I am using the code from NPM lib - powerbi-report-component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Report } from 'powerbi-report-component';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.report = null; // to store the loaded report's object to perform operations like print, full screen etc..
  }
  ...
  handleDataSelected = (data) => {
    // will be called when some chart or data element in your report clicked
  }

  handleReportLoad = (report) => {
    // will be called when report loads:
    // - scripts and data received from server, visuals are rendered on the browser
    // - flickering Power BI logo stops appearing but report is not fully ready to be consumed

    this.report = report; // get the report object from callback and store it.(optional)
  }

  handleReportRender = (report) => {
    // will be called when report renders:
    // - visuals finish rendering
    // - report is fully visible and ready for consumption

    this.report = report; // get the report object from callback and store it.(optional)
  }

  handlePageChange = (data) => {
    // will be called when pages in your report changes
  }

  handleTileClicked = (data) => {
    console.log('Data from tile', data);
  }

  render() {
    const reportStyle = {
        // style object for report component
    };
    const extraSettings = {
            filterPaneEnabled: false, //true
            navContentPaneEnabled: false, //true
            hideErrors: false // Use this *only* when you want to override error experience i.e, use onError
            // ... more custom settings
    };
    return (
    <div className="root">
        <Report
            tokenType="Embed" // "Aad"
            accessToken="" // accessToken goes here
            embedUrl="" // embedUrl goes here
            embedId="" // report or dashboard Id goes here
            pageName="" // set as current page of the report
            reportMode="View" // open report in a particular mode View/Edit/Create
            datasetId={datasetId} // required for reportMode = "Create" and optional for dynamic databinding in `report` on `View` mode
            groupId={groupId} // optional. Used when reportMode = "Create" and to chose the target workspace when the dataset is shared. 
            extraSettings={extraSettings}
            permissions="All" // View, For "Edit" mode permissions should be "All"
            style={reportStyle}
            onLoad={this.handleReportLoad}
            onRender={this.handleReportRender} // not allowed in "Create" mode
            onSelectData={this.handleDataSelected}
            onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
            onTileClicked={this.handleTileClicked}
            onSave={this.handleReportSave} // works for "Edit" and "Create"
        />
    </div>
    );
  }
```

I have tried to capture the event on 'OnLoad'

```
report.on("buttonClicked", event => {
  console.log("buttonClicked", event);
});
```

But we could only capture the events on button click and could not restrict the behavior of this opening on a new tab.

Please help, thanks in advance!!!

Comment: you can't achive this behavior from react side. need to change setting from power bi report generatio side. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-drillthrough